# How to limit a ftp user to only a given subdirectory?

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, vsftpd

I know this question is posted many times on StackExchange, but none of the solutions worked for me.

I use vsftpd server on ubuntu and I want to restrict the access (read-only) for a user to a given subdirectory only. Most of the solutions I found said that changing the home-directory of a user does the job:

```
usermod -d /home/subdirectory <username>
```

with previously setting in `/etc/vsftpd.conf`:

```
local_enable = YES
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
```

and add the username to `/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list`.

Anyway, this works fine if I use a browser. It directs me to the given home directory and I cannot access its parents.

The problem is when I use FileZilla. I connect directly to the home directory but I can also see and access the parent directories (and files within).

I also tried some other solutions using `sftp` with editing the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and using `internal-sftp`, but also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the solution to this problem by setting:

```
chroot_local_user=NO
```

and listing the users in `vsftpd.chroot_list` that CANNOT access the root of the system. Users that are not in this list can still access the root.

Comment: If I am understanding the documentation and your question correctly this will cause any user that is not in the /etc/vsftpd.chroot_list to be given root access.  Good for today because your are aware, maybe not tomorrow.

Comment: @DarkSheep you have misunderstood the documentation. This configuration will allow such unlisted users access to the root filesystem as normal, i.e. they will not be forced into the `chroot`.